# Is it impossible to keep large amounts of Skype contacts organized?

Tags: skype, pidgin, chat

## Is it impossible to keep large amounts of Skype contacts organized?

There seems to be two key features missing:

- Organizing contacts into Lists (recently removed)
- Associating "notes" with contacts

#### Organizing contacts into Lists

This is a feature that they had [until recently](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/forum/skype_mac-skype_messms-skype_instamessms/how-to-recreate-my-contact-lists-in-new-skype/838b5a19-e79e-4e5a-b8aa-3647718551a3), but seems to have been removed with the recent upgrade to the "new and improved" version.

When you have more than 20 or so contacts, this feature is really important. For example, I need to be able to see a list of Linux experts who I have employed over the years - there are at least 15. I'd like to look at that list and see who is online so I can see if they're up to make some quick money helping me out with something.

#### Associating "notes" with contacts

An important feature that seems to always have been missing is the ability to save "notes" with a contact. As far as I can tell, it is not possible to associate extra information with a contact such as "Linux expert who I found on UpWork" or "Person I met while backpacking in Spain".

I can do this on my iPhone, nor sure why its impossible on Skype.

## Ok, so what do I do?

Is there an alternative approach that I should try? It does not have to be free, paid is fine.

#### Universal chat client

I remember back in the day, there was a program called [Pidgin](https://www.pidgin.im/) that combined multiple messaging platforms including AIM. Doesn't look like it supports Skype though. Even the mighty [Slack](https://slack.com/) does not seem to support any meaningful Skype integration.

It seems like the two platforms that are widely used these days by people communicating internationally are WhatsApp and Skype. So a universal chat client that combined these two would be amazing.

#### Multiple Skype accounts

Another approach would be to set up multiple Skype accounts, one for each "list" that I want to monitor. This has some drawbacks, for example: I need to know ahead of time what "list" someone should be on so that I give them the correct Skype handle to contact me at. Also, if I don't use a list for a long time, I'll probably stop signing into it, and then the people on that list won't be able to contact me if they need to.

Note: There seem to be many services available that enable multiple Skype sign on. Example: "All-in-one Messenger" Chrome App. In fact many of the programs that purport to be universal chat clients in fact just allow multiple sign-ins of different chat clients in separate tabs.

#### Native Skype Use Pattern

Perhaps there is some use pattern I can use with the current Skype that I am not seeing that would address these issues?

#### Something else?

Is there an approach that could work nicely that I haven't thought of?

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can go to the profile of each contact you have, then modify the name (there's a little pencil) adding your key-keys (the group-groups). Then you can select from the search box the key... It depends on the number of people you have. (In principle the skype dbase was a mysql3 format, You can backup all, make a query, add in the field-name the name of the group in the previous skype version to the name of the contact...)

Comment: You should update your question as there is a plugin for Pidgin to use Skype